# For each $x \in (0, 1]$, if there is a finite set of intervals $\{I_i\}^n_\mathrm{i=1} \subset S$ whose union contains $[0,x]$, say $x$ is "true"

Tags: real-analysis

Say that $S$ is an infinite collection of non-empty open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ whose union contains $[0,1]$. $$[0,1] \subset \bigcup_\mathrm{I \in S} I$$

For each $x \in (0, 1]$, if there is a finite set of intervals $\{I_i\}^n_\mathrm{i=1} \subset S$ whose union contains $[0,x]$, we will call $x$ an arbitrary condition like "true"

I'm trying to prove that at least one $x \in (0, 1]$ is "true".

Is there an obvious proof of this that I'm missing?

Comment: Every $x$ is true. $S$ is an open cover of the compact set $[0,x]$.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by this? I'm familiar with open covers, but how did you get a compact set?

Answer (score 0):

Every closed interval is a compact set, which means all $x\in(0,1]$ are true.

This is because, for each $x\in (0,1]$, $S$ represents an open cover of $[0,x]$. Since $[0,x]$ is compact, there must, by definition of compactness, exist a finite subcover, which is exactly what you want.

---

If you want to prove your statement without using compactness of closed intervals, then

1. consider some interval $I_0$ such that $0\in I$. You know such an interval exists because $S$ covers $[0,1]$.
2. Let $a,b$ be such that $I=(a,b)$. What can you say about the sign of $b$?
3. Take $x=\frac{b}{2}$. You should then be able to find a finite subcover of $[0,x]$. In fact, that finite subcover contains *one* element!